Change TabNine suggestion text color
Hello I've been using Tabnine recently and the color of those suggestion is to close to a comment is there any way I can change the color of it ?
I've search in the tabnine param but found nothing, is there some code I can change somewhere to change the color.

look in the Tabnine doc if they have a color name that is Themable, and then change it with Theme color customization

Can't find any param that are like this

then you can create a feature request/issue at the extension repo
